# The range of Hausdorff distance values

Tags: hausdorff-distance

What can we interpret if Hausdorff distance between 2 sets is negative or positive? I found that Hausdorff distance equal to zero implies the 2 sets are very close to each other. Also Is Hausdorff symmetric distance.

Comment: Could you please share us what you have tried

Comment: It can't be negative. It's a metric, so it is symmetric, and it's only $0$ if the two sets are identical.

Comment: what we get if 2 sets are not close to each other, will it be a positive value